# Update module twin property for multiple devices

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

When having iot edge with multiple modules running. How to update a desired property of a module twin for multiple devices (100+)?

Using [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-schedule-jobs) seems the way to go for device twins. But I can't get this to work for module twins. Is this not supported (yet)?